# "Repository not found or permission denied" when creating AWS Codebuild Repository

Tags: aws-codebuild

We are trying to create a codebuild in aws and have a private github repository in github, while creating the codebuild section i am getting the **Repository not found or permission denied** error after clicking on create button in code build section.

has someone came across this issue, if so can you please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this issue because I was using a low-privilege account to access GitHub.  CodeBuild needs admin access to the repository in order to create webhooks, so the solution for me was to grant the user admin access to the repo in question (via GitHub, in the repo's Settings page), create the CodeBuild project, then set the user back to read-only.

Comment: Tried the solution, but i'm still unable to resolve the issue. The repo in question is created under my organization account. The account i'm using has admin access to organization as well as the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

CodeBuild > {project} > Sources > Disconnect from GitHub, then Reconnect with a GitHub account where your code repository is.

CodeBuild can only hold one GitHub authentication per account per region.